# Keras 5x faster than Pytorch in basic example

Tags: performance, keras, pytorch

I noticed a big difference in training time for a Keras example and the equivalent Pytorch code, taking this last 5x as much time as Keras. In fact, the DataLoader alone takes more time than Keras. I'm using Pytorch 2.1.1 cpuonly and Keras 2.14. with no gpu in the computer. I've read that Pytorch is not slower than Keras, there is something I'm missing out?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

np.random.seed(42)
X_train = np.random.rand(100000, 10)
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(100000,))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01), metrics= 
['accuracy'])

t0=time()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1024)
print(time() - t0)
```

PyTorch Code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader


X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1024, shuffle=False, 
num_workers=2)

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(10, 64)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(32, 1)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.activation(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.activation(self.layer2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.layer3(x))
        return x

model = MLP()
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

t0 = time()
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:   
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.view(-1, 1))

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
print(time() - t0)
```